# Why in this sentence the writer didn't add articles before British?

Tags: articles

I am reading a story and I noticed that the writer didn't add any article before British and English. For example:

> He can become British, perhaps; he can never become truly English.

Comment: "British" and "English" are both used as adjectives in that sentence, and do not need articles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**become** is often followed by an adjective, as in:

- After working hard, I *became* tired.
- He *became* unhappy with my constant complaints.

It can also be followed by a noun, as in:

- After graduating, I found a job and *became* a librarian.

In the sentence "He can become British, perhaps; he can never become truly English", the words "British" and "English" are adjectives (and therefore no articles are used).

In fact, "British" and "English" cannot be used as nouns referring to individuals (although you can use "the British" and "the English" as plural nouns referring to British or English people collectively, as in "I dislike the British").

So "I became a British" or "I became an English" would be ungrammatical.  You could say "I became a Briton" or "I became an Englishman" - although this would be less usual than using the adjectives.

By contrast, the words "German", "Russian", "American", "Canadian" and "Italian" double up - they are both adjectives and nouns that can be used to refer to particular individuals, as in "I became a German" - but again we would be more likely to say "I became German".

When discussing acquisition of nationality, we are more likely to use adjectives than nouns.  We may add a noun to make clear that it is nationality that is being discussed, as in "I became a British citizen".

The phrase "I became British" is ambiguous - it could refer to acquisition of nationality (formal legal citizenship) or it could refer to becoming British in terms of social habits, behaviour, and so on.

"I became English" cannot (properly) refer to nationality, because legally no such thing as English nationality exists.  There is no English passport - there are British passports.

Comment: ""I dislike the British" - I am intrigued to know why you didn't choose "I admire the British" as your example there. Just asking.

Comment: Feel free to amend it, @MichaelHarvey.  I am British myself.  It was not intended as any kind of statement.  Making up example sentences is a minefield in terms of potentially sending unintended messages, but "admire" would certainly have been a safer choice.  However, perhaps a certain sense of self-deprecatory humour militated against that here.

Comment: You won't remember John Dowie, whose best known record was the 1977 "British Tourist (I Hate the Dutch)"?

Comment: I don't - that was before my time.  I shall look him up.

Answer (score 0):

"He can become British" is not at all incorrect and quite common. It generally means "He can become a British person". It's just a shorter way of writing it. Same with the 'he can never become truly English" portion of the sentence.

Comment: But *why* isn't an article written with 'British'? Answers that say *it's just a shorter version of this and that* are not very useful, IMO.

Comment: Because, as Michael says above, it is an _adjective_ here.